# Cloud storage connected domain with API server

Tags: node.js, express, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I have an app engine nodejs API that serves the API as well as the static files with express, that works great but I would like to split the deploys of API and client.

I created a bucket with the name of my domain name, pointed CNAME record and modified my API server to not serve static files nor index.html.

I uploaded my files to the bucket. And I get the error:

```
AccessDeniedAccess denied.Anonymous caller does not have storage.objects.get access to www.onedeeds.com/index.html.
```

Any help or direction appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are serving a static html directly out of your Google Cloud Storage, you need to make sure you set the files to publicly accessible. See the [documentation here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/hosting-static-website#sharing_your_files) for details.